# Find SUBTOTAL of List at Specific Interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I need to find which row has total sum of next nearest 100 (minimum 100), next total sum must using next value to get total sum.

As example below, because row number will be use to VLOOKUP a data series only when the sum of value equal or minimum every 100.

```
Row    Value    Mapping
---    ------   -------
1      1
2      50
3      52       1 @ (1+50+52=103) Row #3 in Data series return: David
4      72
5      55       2 @ (72+55=127) Row #5 in Data series return: Alex
6      70
7      80       3 @ (70+80=150) Row #7 in Data series return: Alicia
```

At mapping column where I will put VLOOKUP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 as,

```
=IF(AND(SUM(INDEX(B:B, IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99, C$1:C1)+1, 1)):B2)>=100,SUM(INDEX(B:B, IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99, C$1:C1)+1, 1)):B1)<100),MAX(C$1:C1)+1,"")
```

[image: NEXT_100_TOTAL]

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: When I'm changing "MAX(C$1:C1" to VLOOKUP, it stop working. Even when I add additional "IF" at in front of the formula if the result return bigger than 'Zero' then run VLOOKUP, still failed.

Comment: I get that the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) could be used to locate the *1, 2* or *3* and return a value in a column **to the right** but I cannot see how that applies here nor what is intended to returned by the VLOOKUP. If this new situation is going to substantially change the question to the point where this answer no longer is valid, perhaps it would be better to close off this question and initiate another. (see [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625))